# WYSIWYG on panel panes

Tags: 7, panels

Is it possible to use a wysiwyg editor like TinyMCE for editing content in panels.  I want to be able to use TinyMCE for editing 'custom content'.

Another note: is it better to create nodes and just add them to the panel or to use the 'custom content' feature?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time I added Panels to a site, I used this code to preload the required libraries on panels edit pages.

```
  // Panels support.
  if (module_exists('panels') && $form_id == 'panels_edit_display') {
    // Load potential editor.
    foreach (filter_formats() as $format => $object) {
      if ($profile = wysiwyg_get_profile($format)) {
        wysiwyg_load_editor($profile);
        wysiwyg_add_plugin_settings($profile);
        wysiwyg_add_editor_settings($profile, 'advanced');
      }
    }
  }
```

From http://drupal.org/node/356480#comment-1190907 and the patch located in http://drupal.org/node/356480#comment-4256204.

This setup worked with:

- Drupal 7.0
- Latest WYSIWYG 7.x-2.x-dev from git
- CKEditor 3.6
- Panels 7.x-3.0-alpha3
- CTools 7.x-1.0-alpha4