# Full HTML Formatter / WYSIWYG Not Working In Views 3?

Tags: 7, views, input-formats

I have a Drupal 7 site that I've been plugging away at for the last few weeks, and I noticed that when I'm in Views and am trying to add a Global Text Area to the footer of my view (for a "Read More" link that goes to a custom page), the WYSIWYG formatter does not show up at all. The dropdown to pick formats appears, but none of them initiate TinyMCE.

The strange thing is that the Input Formats are configured just fine for the rest of the site and proper user roles. It works across all of the content types I have set up. So, my question is, how can I get this working so that I can put a link in the footer?

For sake of explaining things better, here's a screenshot. Note that this problem is only happening in Views.

[image: Weird Input Format Problem in Views]

Comment: Is this within a modal popup window? Are you seeing any JavaScript errors in your browser console?

Comment: Yeah, it is a popup modal window. I'm not really seeing any JavaScript errors in my console in Chrome, but I'll look again. Where exactly does one look for JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: If you're running Firefox with Firebug, hit F12 and any JS errors should be printed in the console.

Comment: Upon running the Firebug console, it's not finding any errors when I try and recreate the problem. The problem DOES persist, however.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a lazy-load editor problem. The WYSIWYG libraries aren't being loaded on the parent page, so they are not available to the modal window. If you're using the WYSIWYG module with CKEditor, something like this should alleviate your issue.

```
<?php
  // Views support.
  if (module_exists('views') && $form_id == 'views_ui_edi') {
    // Load potential editor.
    foreach (filter_formats() as $format => $object) {
      if ($profile = wysiwyg_get_profile($format)) {
        wysiwyg_load_editor($profile);
        wysiwyg_add_plugin_settings($profile);
        wysiwyg_add_editor_settings($profile, 'advanced');
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

from http://drupal.org/node/356480#comment-1190907

and the patch located in -

http://drupal.org/node/356480#comment-4256204

Comment: Here's a similar issue... http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7428/wysiwyg-on-panel-panes/7646#7646

Comment: Would this work with TinyMCE, do you think?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it will work with TinyMCE, because I have not tried it myself yet. There are many people in the thread I mentioned above [link](http://drupal.org/node/356480) saying that this fix does not work with TinyMCE.